# OBS Studio how to set options programmatically

Tags: python, lua, obs

writing a plugin for OBS Studio, I am stuck on trying to set recording filename/path using luaobs or obspython

```
Settings->Advanced->Filename Formatting
or
Settings->Output->Recording Path
```

how would i go about setting those settings programmatically?

Comment: Im starting to think that config_set_string is missing from obspython and that i will need to rewrite the whole script from python to C
https://obsproject.com/docs/reference-libobs-util-config-file.html?highlight=config_set_string#c.config_set_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the bindings for SetFilenameFormatting are missing in obspython, to fix this issue i switched to OBS-WebSocket-py library

```
import obswebsocket
import obswebsocket.requests

client = obswebsocket.obsws("localhost", 4444, "")
client.connect()
client.call(obswebsocket.requests.SetFilenameFormatting(file_name + " - %CCYY-%MM-%DD %hh-%mm-%ss"))
client.disconnect()
```